# Whats the use of Collection<? extends SomeAbstractClass> instead of Collection<SomeAbstractClass>

Tags: java, generics

So lets say we have an Java Application with an abstract class named `SomeAbstractClass` and at least 10 subclasses of this super class.

Whats the use of using this abstract super class in generics in the way `Collection<? extends SomeAbstractClass>` instead of just using `Collection<SomeAbstractClass>`

Maybe I missed something very fundamental stuff inside generics.

Comment: Read this. Exactly what you want to know.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: "The term List<Number> is more restrictive than List<? extends Number> because the former matches a list of type Number only, whereas the latter matches a list of type Number or any of its subclasses." From the resource, SURESH linked above.

Comment: You can have a look at this. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between these two declarations:

```
Collection<? extends A> c1;
Collection<A> c2;
```

Is that c2 can hold instances of A or any subclass, but c1 can hold instances of some unknown but particular subclass of A (or A) or any of the unknown class's subclasses.

You can't add items to c2 because the compiler doesn't know what type it is, only that if you get one out it can be cast to A.

Further, you can not assign (ie cast) c1 to c2 - c1 is not a subclass of c2's type.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards in generics are for Collection Type and typically not for element being stored.

For example imagine a method which takes argument `List<Number>`.

```
public void calculateSum(List<Number> numbers) {
    for (Number n: numbers) {
       // calculate Sum
   }
}
```

Now, if we want to calculate sum of Integers by passing `List<Integer>` as follows. (Note that `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`)

```
List<Integer> integers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Populate collection
calculateSum(integers);  //Error
```

This will not work as even though `Integers` is a subtype of `Number` `List<Integers>` is **not a subType** of `List<Number>`. Note that `List<Number>` can still store `Integer`,`Float`,`Double` etc.

So, to have a generic method to calculate the sum of any type of `Number` we use wildcard as follows

```
public void calculateSum(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
    for (Number n: numbers) {
       // calculate Sum
   }
}
```

This will calculate the sum of any type of numbers provided that type extends `Number`

Answer (score 0):

The  below is [not true in generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html),

```
Collection<? extends SomeAbstractClass> 
              ^
              |
              |
Collection<SomeAbstractClass>
```

`Collection<? extends SomeAbstractClass>` and `Collection<SomeAbstractClass>` are completely different types and not related.

Note that,

> Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer),
>   MyClass has no relationship to MyClass, regardless of whether or
>   not A and B are related.

For example, `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` even though Integer is a subtype of Number.

Answer (score -2):

In your case it makes no difference since the type is abstract but in general `Collection<SomeClass>` can contain `SomeClass` and all it's subclasses while `Collection<? extends SomeClass>` cannot contain `SomeClass` but only it's subclasses.

You can try it yourself.

```
List<Number> foo = new ArrayList<>();
foo.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
```

works while

```
List<? extends Number> foo = new ArrayList<>();
foo.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
```

doesn't. It shows the error `"The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Number) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Number> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)"`

Comment: -1 completely incorrect. The generic bound `? extends X` includes `X` - it can contain instances of `X` too. And there's no apostrophe in "its"... so there

Comment: "The term List<Number> is more restrictive than List<? extends Number> because the former matches a list of type Number only, whereas the latter matches a list of type Number or any of its subclasses." from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html tells a different story ...

Comment: @Fildor that sounds a little strange to me since it definitely doesn't match the actual behaviour. See the example from my edit.

Comment: You are way off base. You should read some generics tutorials.

Comment: @Bohemian that's exactly how it behaves inside Eclipse. I tried it. Tell me what's wrong about it.

Comment: Your explanation is totally wrong: You have no idea about what's going on here. Read my answer for a very brief start, then follow the link posted by Fildor. Generic bounds don't work like class hierarchies - it takes a while to get the hang of it.

Comment: @Bohemian so far nothing new to me and by thinking of it again helped. I now realize I made a fallacy or better said didn't think the explaination for the behaviour in my examples all the way through. Thanks!